# How do I find the absolute position of an element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way of finding the absolute position of an element, i.e. relative to the start of the window, using jQuery?

Comment: If you need the `position:absolute;` value of the child, use JQuery's [.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

Answer (score 699, accepted):

[`.offset()`](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset) will return the offset position of an element as a simple object, eg:

```
var position = $(element).offset(); // position = { left: 42, top: 567 }
```

You can use this return value to position other elements at the same spot:

```
$(anotherElement).css(position)
```

Comment: I always forget this one, and find your post again when I google :p

Comment: This does not always seem to return the absolute position due to differences in borders etc.

Comment: I'm using chrome and the `offset()` does not return the proper top coordinate.  It returns about 300 pixels more than the top coordinate of the element in the document instead.  Why??

Comment: chrome, FF and IE are giving different results :(

Comment: @SoLoGHoST this problem appears in the android webview as well :/

Comment: @Aren I always forget this one and find your comment amusing every time :)

Comment: Great.. I forgot that offset() result is related to the position into the document. Thanks!

Comment: @SoLoGHoST Try `$(element).position()` **(** `$(element).position().top` & `$(element).position().left` **)**

Answer (score 222):

Note that `$(element).offset()` tells you the position of an element *relative to the document*. This works great in most circumstances, but in the case of **`position:fixed`** you can get unexpected results.

If your document is *longer than the viewport* and you have scrolled vertically toward the bottom of the document, then your `position:fixed` element's `offset()` value **will be greater than** the expected value by the amount you have scrolled.

If you are looking for a value *relative to the viewport* (window), rather than the document on a position:fixed element, you can subtract the document's `scrollTop()` value from the fixed element's `offset().top` value. Example: `$("#el").offset().top - $(document).scrollTop()`

If the `position:fixed` element's offset parent is the *document*, you want to read `parseInt($.css('top'))` instead.

Comment: I was looking exactly for this! For the noob like me: the value to be subtracted is `$(document).scrollTop()`

Answer (score 0):

In case the element is not visible `$(element).offset();` and `$(element).position();` retun `0` for both `top` and `left` instead of the elements real value.

i had to use

```
parseInt($(element).css("top"))
parseInt($(element).css("left"))
```

to return the needed information.
the element has `position: absolute;`.