# getting div current placement

Tags: jquery

How can I get the div's current postion with jQuery  or divs current placement with jQuery

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var position = jQuery('#myelement').position();
alert(position.left);
alert(position.top);
```

Comment: `#position` gives the position relative to the offset parent. The OP didn't exactly give us much to work with, but I'm guessing he needs relative to the doc (`#offset`). And yes, those names seem backward to me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ["CSS" section of the jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS), in particular the `#offset` function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean position on your web page? This depends on the browser you are using. 
They handle code in a different way sometomes...

You can check your app via Firebug in Firefox or Webdeveloper Toolbar in Internet Explorer for getting the right values.

Answer (score 0):

try `position` function.

```
var pos=$("#ID_OF_DIV").position();

alert("TOP: " + pos.top +"\r\nLEFT: " + pos.left);
```