# how do I get co-ordinates of selected text in an html using javascript document.getSelecttion()

Tags: javascript, getselection

I would like to position element above selected text. But I am not able to figure out the coordinates.

```
var sel = document.getSelection();
  if(sel != null) {
    positionDiv();
}
```

Example: (image)

[image]

Comment: Please post code for a specific answer.

Comment: ok. updated with more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589721/how-can-i-position-an-element-next-to-user-text-selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the basic idea. You insert dummy element in the beginning of the selection and get the coordinates of that dummy html element. Then you remove it.

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var dummy = document.createElement("span");
range.insertNode(dummy);
var box = document.getBoxObjectFor(dummy);
var x = box.x, y = box.y;
dummy.parentNode.removeChild(dummy);
```

Comment: Take a look here, it might be a better way to determine the dummy's position - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

I usually use jQuery and the offset plugin so I don't have issues with browser compatibility.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link for jquery plugin? thanks.

Comment: None of this will work in IE, which has a completely different mechanism for obtaining and manipulating user selections. Also, `document.getBoxObjectFor` is a Mozilla extension that is now deprecated, and was never intended for use in web pages in the first place.

Comment: @Tim: `document.getBoxObjectFor` is completely gone as of FF 3.6.

Comment: The library is jquery.com here is example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: `dummy.getBoundingClientRect()` is a suitable replacement for `document.getBoxObjectFor(dummy)`