# Diff between document.getSelection() and window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript

Also can you please answer this question?
[how do I get co-ordinates of selected text in an html using javascript document.getSelecttion()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605133/how-do-i-get-co-ordinates-of-selected-text-in-an-html-using-javascript-document-g)

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I get co-ordinates of selected text in an html using javascript document.getSelecttion()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605133/how-do-i-get-co-ordinates-of-selected-text-in-an-html-using-javascript-document)

Comment: You mean `document.selection` perhaps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get error message `Deprecated method document.getSelection()` called. Please use `window.getSelection()` instead." in Firefox which means `document.getSelection()` is a deprecated method.

Comment: Not anymore. It's perfectly valid in current Firefox.

Comment: IMHO `document.getSelection()` is more intuitive than `window.getSelection()`. For example, the `selectionchange` event won't work on `window` object but it works on `document` object, so it makes more sense to stick with `document.getSelection()` to be more consistent.

Answer (score 2):

They seem to be the same:

https://w3c.github.io/selection-api/#dom-document-getselection

> `getSelection()` method
> The method must return the selection associated with `this` if `this` has an associated browsing context, and it must return null otherwise.

https://w3c.github.io/selection-api/#dom-window-getselection

> `getSelection()` method
> The method must invoke and return the result of `getSelection()` on `this`'s `Window.document` attribute.

Editors of MDN say they're equivalent:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection

> You can call `Window.getSelection()`, which works identically to `Document.getSelection()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

> You can call `Document.getSelection()`, which works identically to `Window.getSelection()`.