# How to get the coordinates of the end of selected text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, getselection

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605133/how-do-i-get-co-ordinates-of-selected-text-in-an-html-using-javascript-document-g), but I need a way to get the coordinates of the right side of the selection with Javascript in Firefox. I made a small example to show what I mean:

[image]

The code I got from the other post is the following:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var dummy = document.createElement("span");
range.insertNode(dummy);
var box = document.getBoxObjectFor(dummy);
var x = box.x, y = box.y;
dummy.parentNode.removeChild(dummy);
```

This gives me the coordinates of the beginning of the selection. Is there any way to retrieve the coordinates of the end of the selection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. That bit's quite simple: you just need to call `collapse(false)` on the Range obtained from the selection. Be aware that `document.getBoxObjectFor()` has now been removed from Mozilla, so you need the dummy element's [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.getBoundingClientRect) method instead:

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.collapse(false);
var dummy = document.createElement("span");
range.insertNode(dummy);
var rect = dummy.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = rect.left, y = rect.top;
dummy.parentNode.removeChild(dummy);
```

Comment: +1 for being 3 seconds faster.  I didn't know *getBoxObjectFor()* had already been removed.

Comment: I remembered that because a few months ago MooTools broke because it was detecting Mozilla using a sniff for `getBoxObjectFor()` (a method that it never used, as far as I know).

Comment: collapse(false) is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you so much. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = range.cloneRange();
r.collapse(false); // collapses range clone to end of original range
r.insertNode(dummy);
// document.getBoxObjectFor(dummy), etc.
```