# Create tooltip at cursor position in text area with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a tooltip above the input caret in a text area. This would be easy if I could get the x,y coordinates of the caret in the text area, however I've been searching for a little while and cannot figure out how to do that.

Say a user is typing in a text area and then presses some key (@ symbol for instance). I'm trying to show a little tooltip above the text area caret.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Comment: @FloydPink I do know how to create a tooltip. The question is wether it's possible to create the tooltip at the caret position in a textarea.

Comment: Did some Googling and I think this is what you are looking for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605133/how-do-i-get-co-ordinates-of-selected-text-in-an-html-using-javascript-document-g

Comment: None of the methods for doing this are in any way cross browser btw.

Comment: @BNL yeah what would those methods be?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm I do not really see anything in jQuery events that will easily give you an x y coord for the caret.

However there are quite a few ways for detecting the caret position in a text field:

http://laboratorium.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.1.0/test.html

[Is it possible to programmatically detect the caret position within a <input type=text> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185821/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-detect-the-caret-position-within-a-input-type)

[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

Using this, you could try to estimate the pixel coordinates for the tool tip.

If you want it to be more exact use a monospaced font inside of your text fields.

```
//depending on size of font
var charWidth = 10;
//using any number of the above methods to get caret position
var caretPosition = getCaretPos('#myTextField');
var textFieldOffsetX = $('#myTextField').offset.left;
var toopTipPositionX = caretPosition * charWidth + textFieldOffsetX;
```

It is not exact and it is not going to be perfect, but it might be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the tooltip have to be at the caret? Why not position it above (or somewhere around) the textarea? Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fBUaz/1/) of what I mean.

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        // @ symbol
    case 50:
        makeTooltip(e, 'you typed in an at symbol');
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Because if you have a big textarea it can be positioned out of the screen.