# How to place one element exactly to the same visible position, as another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I have two elements "src" and "dest"

"src" and "dest" are in different DOM-nodes, that can not have the same parent.

I need to place "src" element in the same visible position, as "dest".

"src" element must also have the same sizes, as "dest".

I have following code for case, when "src" and "dest" having the same parent:

```
src.css("position", "absolute");
src.css("top", dest.offset().top);
src.css("left", dest.offset().left);
src.width(dest.width());

// Show "src" element, instead of "dest". "src" must be in the same visible position, as "dest"
dest.css("opacity", 0);
src.show();
```

Unfortunately, it does not works. "src" element has displacement to bottom and left, for that i cannot find the reason.

Maybe, i do something wrong ...

How to do it right for two cases ?

1. "src" and "dest" having the same grand-parent
2. "src" and "dest" does't having the same parent. Maybe grand-grand-grand-parent is the common for both.

---

Update:

I have arranged a simple HMTL document, that does a simple visual swapping of one element with another:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MacBlog</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .dest {
            background-color: #0cf;
            width: 480px;
            height: 320px;
        }
        .src {
            background-color: #09c;
            width: 1024px;
            height: 768px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        jQuery(function($){
            // Common items, to deal with
            var src = $(".src");
            var dest = $(".dest");
            // Setup
            src.hide();
            // Interaction
            dest.click(function(){
                src.width(dest.width());
                src.height(dest.height());
                src.offset(dest.offset());

                dest.hide();
                src.show();
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!--On clicking, this element should visually be swapped by ".src" element -->
        <div class="dest"><p>dest</p></div>
        <div class="src"><p>src</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It does not work correctly. After "swapping", "src" element has a strange displacement to top-left direction on ~30 pixels.

I use latest version of Safari 5, if i makes sense.

---

Update 2:

Unfortunately, this also does not works. I updated my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MacBlog</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        div {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .holder {
            position: relative;
            top: 40pt;
            left: 40pt;
            border: black solid thin;
        }
        .dest {
            background-color: #0cf;
            width: 480px;
            height: 320px;
        }
        .src {
            background-color: #09c;
            width: 1024px;
            height: 768px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        jQuery(function($){
            // Common items, to deal with
            var src = $(".src");
            var dest = $(".dest");
            // Setup
            src.hide();
            // Interaction
            dest.click(function(){
                src.css("position", "absolute");
                src.width(dest.width());
                src.height(dest.height());
                src.offset(dest.offset());

                dest.hide();
                src.show();
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="holder">
        <!--On clicking, this element should visually be swapped by ".src" element -->
        <div class="dest"><p>dest</p></div>
        <div class="src"><p>src</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery/683564#683564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it here:http://jsfiddle.net/YEzWj/1/

Using your second example make your CSS like this:

```
div { 
    position:relative;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
} 
.holder { 
    position: relative; 
    top: 40pt; 
    left: 40pt; 
    border: black solid thin; 
} 
.dest { 
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #0cf; 
    width: 480px; 
    height: 320px; 
} 
.src { 
    background-color: #09c; 
    width: 1024px; 
    height: 768px; 
}
```

EDIT:  After playing around with it some, it did not work in all circumstances. I decided to change the javascript.  Note: My example toggles the display of src and dest within the holder, making holder the same size as dest so the border shows outside the dest and src.

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    // Common items, to deal with 
    var src = $(".src"); 
    var dest = $(".dest");
    var holder=$(".holder");
    holder.width(dest.width()); 
    holder.height(dest.height());
    // Setup 
    src.hide(); 
    // Interaction 
    dest.click(function(){ 
        src.show();
        src.css("position", "absolute"); 
        src.width(dest.width()); 
        src.height(dest.height()); 
        src.offset(dest.offset()); 
        dest.hide();
     }); 
    src.click(function(){ 
        dest.show();
        src.hide(); 
    }); 

});
```

EDIT2: Remove the src.click() event if you wish it to NOT go back to the dest on src click.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `dest` element absolute, otherwise the `top` and `left` offsets will not apply.

```
src.css('position', 'absolute'); // ensure position is set to absolute
src.offset(dest.offset());
```

Also, elements like `p` and body will have default stylesheets depending on browser. So try to supply a reset style to make things consistent:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried, that you advised, and this does not works. See "update 2" of my question. Could you make "Update 2" working ? This is not so simple, as i thought ...

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [`offset` function](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to set the offset and handle different parents correctly, like this:

```
dest.offset(src.offset());
```