# Get screenX for DOM element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

When I listen for mouseover on an element, I get an event fired that has screenX, clientX, pageX and lots of other nice details about where the mouse is relative to the screen and relative to the element that fired the event.

If I just call element.mouseover(), my handler runs, but the mouse location and other properties are all null. I looked at initMouseEvent, but it requires you specify screenX which I don't know.

My question is, how can I get these values without the mouse being over the element or even in the window at all?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I thought my question was pretty clear - I'm looking to get the screenX/Y for a DOM element without the mouse being over it or even in the window which I can easily get when the mouse is over the element or even in the window by comparing offsets.

Comment: So, why cant you just use jQuery's position http://api.jquery.com/position/  or the traditional ways of getting X and Y coords? And are you trying to get all these info just  to simulate a mouse event?

Comment: .position() and .offset() are relative to the parent and document respectively, not the screen. And no I don't want to simulate a mouse event but that would solve my problem if I could simulate one with the values populated.

Comment: does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript:

```
function getScreenCoords(element) {
    let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
            x: window.screenX + rect.left,
            y: window.screenY + rect.top
        }
}
```