# how to get callback when an element enters another element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `div.contentArea` that contains some contents with scrollbar. It was defined that when the mouse enters `div.content` , return ID of the content and some more ajax action with this jQuery code:

```
$('.contentAarea').on('mouseenter','.content',function(){
    var getId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(getId);
    // some more ajax actions.
});
```

for more details: http://jsfiddle.net/mr_mohsen_rasouli/4Nb9L/10/

now i define a `div.mark` element with `fixed` position and want when I scroll or up down and a `div.mark` enter the `div.content` , do action.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230029/jquery-javascript-collision-detection

Comment: I was a bit confused. Can you explain a little more aboute JS in http://jsfiddle.net/98sAG/ ...?!

Comment: is this something you are looking for? http://jsbin.com/gehofacu/1

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

`on("mousenter",function(evt){
 }`

`evt` is an object that contains some very helpfull information about the position of the cursor. A very ineresting attribute is the `currentTarget` that contains the element the cursor is in, complete with class name and id.

Also you can use `console.log` to print messages in the console and avoid alerts

I don't quite understand what you want to do with that information because your english isn't very good but if you explain better I can help you.

Comment: I don't want to use mouse or mouse event. I wanna that when the `.mark` box go into the `.content` do some actions like alert!

Comment: you should read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery