# offset().top is not working as expected in if parent element is fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using `position : fixed` for a div for stick that div on top of the page, but when i use `offset().top` for its child value, it gives different values on scrolling. i tried like :

CSS :

```
.parent{
    position : fixed;
    top : 0px;
}
.child{
    height : 20px;
    margin-top : 10px;
}
```

JS :

```
console.log($(".child").offset().top);
```

the above JS code give different results when i scrolling the page.

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle to show the problem? I would guess you need `position().top` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use .position() to get the current coordinates of an element relative to its offset parent. The .offset() method is gives you the coordinates relative to the entire document.

```
$(".child").position()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you can read here: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

The offset().top gives you the pixels from the element to the top of the page.

Maybe you should use .position().top quote from http://api.jquery.com/offset/

> Contrast this with .position(), which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `position.top` to get the top position for the div http://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score -1):

You may check the link below. There is the explanation how to calculate top position taking scrollTop into account. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10340741/851516