# How to get coordinates of div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, coordinates, offset

I am trying to find out the coordinates of a div with an id of #23 when a button is clicked, the button is called arrowR. Problem is it keeps returning the coordinates of where the mouse is on the button. Is there any way to get the coordinates of the div within the page when the button is clicked? The script which I am using is below:

```
$('#arrowR').click(function(e)
{   

    var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $('#23').scrollLeft();

    var left = Math.round( (e.clientX - offset_l) );



if (left != 62) {
    alert("Left: " + left );
    } else {
    alert("works");
    }


});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: Have tried this but it is returning NaN?

Comment: Coordinates of what div? You haven't provided any html. We have no idea what your goal is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the offset of the button, you want the offset of the div:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/exw7qs9d/2/)**

```
$('#arrowR').click(function (e) {
    var coords = $('#23').offset(); // <-- This.
    $('#coords-left').val(coords.left);
    $('#coords-top').val(coords.top);
});
```

I've positioned an element absolutely at the coordinates so you can see in the fiddle that it matches.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [How do I find the absolute position of an element using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery)

`var position = $(element).offset();`