# same onclick js function for multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gallery of images. I want to show a loading gif when an image is clicked. I am passing the same `onclick` function to all the images with their id as below:

```
<div id="smallimage1" onclick="imageClicked(this.id)">                                                                                  
    <img class="model-img" src="img/model/image1.jpeg"/>                                                                                
</div>

<div id="smallimage2" onclick="imageClicked(this.id)">                                                                                  
    <img class="model-img" src="img/model/image2.jpeg"/>                                                                        
</div>

<div id="loading" style="margin-top: -65%; display: none; z-index= 9999; position: relative;">                                                                      
    <img src="img/imagepreloader.gif" alt="loading...">                                                                                 
</div>
```

This is my js :

```
function imageClicked(id) {
    //  alert(id);
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = ""; // to display
    //alert(loading);
    return true;
}

var FirstLoading = true;

function Restoresmallimage() {
    if (FirstLoading) {
        FirstLoading = false;
        return;
    }
}

// To disable restoring submit button, disable or delete next line.
document.onfocus = Restoresmallimage;
```

For the first image its working fine.
But issue is when I am clicking on second image, gif is running on first image and not on the second one. How to resolve this issue? I had defined loading id in each div image.

Comment: Update the position of the `loading` div when image is clicked..Or you should have multiple `loading` elements associated with each `image`

Comment: Just FYI `z-index= 9999` should be `z-index: 9999`

Comment: Yes I have defined multiple loading element for each image. there is one div in which there is image div and loading div. But gif is not moving on clicking different image.

Comment: If You use Id to select the loading image then it will get the first element with that Id always. So Id of an element have to be unique always.Try selecting the next element  to that Id ie) loading imageYou have passed to that function

Comment: If you have multiple why are you using an ID? IDs are supposed to be unique and should be usually avoided

Comment: @Rayon seems to have answered your question. If you go for the updating the position of the loading gif this post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: Are you using multiple loading element with same ID(loading)?

Comment: you should use multiple loading element with different Ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it will work,

```
<div id="smallimage1" onclick="imageClicked(this.id)">                                                                                  
    <img class="model-img" src="img/model/image1.jpeg"/>                                                                                
</div>

<div id="smallimage2" onclick="imageClicked(this.id)">                                                                                  
    <img class="model-img" src="img/model/image2.jpeg"/>                                                                        
</div>

<div id="loading1" style="margin-top: -65%; display: none; z-index:9999; position: relative;">                                                                      
    <img src="img/imagepreloader.gif" alt="loading...">                                                                                 
</div>

<div id="loading2" style="margin-top: -65%; display: none; z-index: 9999; position: relative;">                                                                      
    <img src="img/imagepreloader.gif" alt="loading...">                                                                                 
</div>
```

And your script will be like this;

```
function imageClicked(id) {
    //  alert(id);
    var loadingId = $(id).replace('smallimage','loading');
    document.getElementById(loadingId).style.display = "block"; // to display
    //alert(loading);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. Its not working. :(  preloading image not  showing.

Comment: Kinjal's code looks like it needs the loading divs to be  placed inside the smallimage divs & shouldn't style.display = "" be = "block" ? @Abhishek - any chance of a jSFiddle which we could fix for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you never move `imagepreloader.gif`. Here is my solution to have only one `imagepreloader.gif` for all images:

HTML:

```
<div id="smallimage1" onclick="imageClicked(this.id)">
    <img class="model-img" src="img/model/image1.jpeg"/>
</div>

<div id="smallimage2" onclick="imageClicked(this.id)">
    <img class="model-img" src="img/model/image2.jpeg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function constructImagePreloader() {
    'use strict';

    var imagePreloader = document.createElement('img');

    imagePreloader.setAttribute('src', 'images/imagepreloader.gif');
    imagePreloader.setAttribute('alt', 'loading...');
    imagePreloader.setAttribute('id', 'loading');

    return imagePreloader;
}

function imageClicked(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(constructImagePreloader());

    return true;
}
```

Tell me if it suits your needs. We could go further with code optimization but I wanted to stay close from your code for now. For instance: we could remove the image preloader from the clicked image if another image is clicked.