# Find closest element with given class JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this `HTML`:

```
<div class="field select">
    <div class="FormToolTipContainer">
        <h2>Details</h2>
        <div class="FormToolTip">&#63;                                                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                                    
<div class="FormToolTipText"><strong>Tool tip:</strong> Add details here</div>
```

Then I have this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".FormToolTip").hover(function () {
        var ToolTipDiv = $(this).closest('.FormToolTipText');

        ToolTipDiv.toggle();

        var ToolTipOffset = $('.FormToolTip').offset();
        ToolTipOffset.top = ToolTipOffset.top + 40;
        ToolTipDiv.css(ToolTipOffset);

    }, function () {
        var ToolTipDiv = $(this).find(':first-child');
        ToolTipDiv.toggle();
    });
});
```

Where I am trying to find the element `FormToolTipText` by using the `closest` selector on `this` but it is not work.

I have also tried `next` but that does not work.

Is it because the element `FormToolTipText` is outside `FormToolTip`

As far as I can see I have followed these instructions here:
https://api.jquery.com/next/
https://api.jquery.com/closest/

and numerous SO questions, but none of them will select the element I have tried.

As I said, I have tried every variation I can think of, and everything I can find but none of them work.

Basically I am trying to make a tooltip and need to navigate to the closest div with the class `FormToolTipText` but can only do so in relation to `this`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.FormToolTipText` is not the parent of the `.FormToolTip`. So you cannot get it at all. What you need to do is, using `.closest()` get the parent and use `.next()` to traverse to `.FormToolTipText`:

```
var ToolTipDiv = $(this).closest('.field').next('.FormToolTipText');
```

Answer (score 2):

`closest()` only looks at parent elements whereas you need to go up two levels then find the next element.

Also note that your use of `css()` is incorrect too - you need to specify the CSS property you want to amend. Try this:

```
$(".FormToolTip").hover(function() {
    var $tooltipDiv = $(this).closest('.field').next('.FormToolTipText').toggle();
    var toolipOffset = $(this).offset();
    $tooltipDiv.css('top', toolipOffset.top + 40); // this is a guess, amend as needed
}, function() {
    var $tooltipDiv = $(this).find(':first-child');
    $tooltipDiv.toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a note you can pass in the whole offset, as well as inidividual coordinates. Please see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683339/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: True. Just be careful when doing that, as although the object property names match they may not always be the expected values due to differing positions relative to parent elements and the window